# Slick2D Java TiledMap GetTileID()

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

im currently trying to write a little game in java with the slick2d library. 
The problem is that my collission detection is not working because getTileId returns the wrong values.
This is my init method:

```
    public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    grassMap = new TiledMap("data/grassmap.tmx");
    blocked = new boolean[grassMap.getWidth()][grassMap.getHeight()];
    player1 = new Player((int)x,(int)y,RADIUS);
    for(int x = 1; x < grassMap.getHeight() ; x++) {
        for(int y = 1; y < grassMap.getWidth() ; y++) {
              int tileID = grassMap.getTileId(x, y, 0);
              System.out.println(tileID);
                 String value = grassMap.getTileProperty(tileID, "blocked", "false");
                 if (value.equals("true"))
                 {
                     blocked[x][y] = true;
                 } else {
                     blocked[x][y] = false;
                 }
        }
    }
```

The method getTileId somehow only returns 2 or 22 and i dont know why.

Here is my TiledMap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="10" height="10" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="grass" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <properties>
   <property name="blocked" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <image source="grass.png" width="128" height="128"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="17" name="rocks" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <properties>
   <property name="blocked" value="true"/>
  </properties>
  <image source="rocks.png" width="128" height="128"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Kachelebene 1" width="10" height="10">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACxNjYGAQIxIzEcDkqMNnD7o6dDPooY6a/iUGAwD5PKE9kAEAAA==
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Comment: Can you post up your .tmx file(map file made in Tiled)? That's really the only way we could check what the map data has. And you're sure it only returns 2 or 22?

Comment: Added. Yes im sure :)